# Connecting NodeJS backend to SQL Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I created a test.udl file in order to test the connection to my SQL Server database to see if there were any problems with the connection, everything went as expected and the message Test Connection Succeeded was returned, the information I entered was as follows:
[image]

[image]

After that I tried to edit my code in the config / db.js file as follows:

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";

const dbInstance = new Sequelize ('DOCFLOW', '', '', {
  dialect: 'mssql',
  host: '(localdb)',
  dialectOptions: {
      // Observe the need for this nested options field for MSSQL
      options: {
          useUTC: false,
          dateFirst: 1,
          enableArithAbort: true,
          encrypt: false,
          trustServerCertificate: true,
          instanceName: 'Local',
          trustedConnection: true,
          schema: 'ERPMASTER',
      }
  }
});

export { dbInstance };
```

The terminal is returning the following errors:
[image]

Comment: If you're using Sequelize then you don't want to use `{ host: '(localdb)' }`... because `(localdb)` isn't a host name and Sequelize doesn't understand the Server Aliases that SQL Server Native Client and ODBC Driver for SQL Server use.

Comment: Do you have ODBC Driver 17 (or 18) for SQL Server installed? Have you tried using `{ dialectOptions: { options: { connectionString: 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=(localdb)\\Local;...' } } } }` instead?

Comment: Doesn't work keep with same error

Comment: find the ip / port you're using instead. it should be something like: localhost:1433